# Spring-mvc org.xml.sax.SAXParseException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

Using Maven and Spring and Hibernate and Jetty
i just copied the web.xml and the servlet-xml from a working project to a new project 
i have only changed the DAO and Services to make them Generic 
and i got this exception

```
[INFO] No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
[INFO] Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Jun 04, 2014 12:34:02 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
Jun 04, 2014 12:34:02 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefre
sh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Wed Jun 04 12:3
4:02 AST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jun 04, 2014 12:34:03 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefin
itions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
Jun 04, 2014 12:34:24 PM org.springframework.util.xml.SimpleSaxErrorHandler warning
WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd; l
ineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 151; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.spr
ingframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the do
cument could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Error
HandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.j
ava:99)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.jav
a:433)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandl
er.java:4162)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(XSDH
andler.java:4157)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHa
ndler.java:2490)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHan
dler.java:2187)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler
.java:2078)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandle
r.java:1008)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.j
ava:620)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.jav
a:616)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchema
Validator.java:2453)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchem
aValidator.java:1773)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValid
ator.java:766)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDo
cumentScannerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDri
ver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImp
l.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScanne
rImpl.java:117)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDo
cumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.ja
va:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.ja
va:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.jav
a:348)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentL
oader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBe
anDefinitionReader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBean
DefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBean
DefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlW
ebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlW
ebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFact
ory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(Abs
tractApplicationContext.java:540)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicatio
nContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext
(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:657)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServl
et.java:525)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:46
6)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:612)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java
:110)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:
156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:371)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:307)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:203)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.j
ava:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBu
ilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBu
ilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(Si
ngleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1167)

        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1103)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:997)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1511)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1439)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityMana
ger.java:640)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersion
Detector.java:189)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingCo
nfig.java:582)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingCo
nfig.java:685)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.jav
a:530)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHan
dler.java:2175)
        ... 80 more

Jun 04, 2014 12:34:45 PM org.springframework.util.xml.SimpleSaxErrorHandler warning
WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-contex
t.xsd; lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 150; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http:/
/www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-4.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2
) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Error
HandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.j
ava:99)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.jav
a:433)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandl
er.java:4162)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(XSDH
andler.java:4157)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHa
ndler.java:2490)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHan
dler.java:2187)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.resolveSchema(XSDHandler
.java:2078)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.constructTrees(XSDHandle
r.java:1008)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.j
ava:620)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.jav
a:616)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchema
Validator.java:2453)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchem
aValidator.java:1773)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValid
ator.java:766)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDo
cumentScannerImpl.java:355)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDri
ver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2770)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImp
l.java:606)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScanne
rImpl.java:117)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDo
cumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.ja
va:848)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.ja
va:777)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.jav
a:348)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentL
oader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBe
anDefinitionReader.java:388)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBean
DefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBean
DefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinition
s(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlW
ebApplicationContext.java:125)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlW
ebApplicationContext.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFact
ory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(Abs
tractApplicationContext.java:540)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicatio
nContext.java:454)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext
(FrameworkServlet.java:643)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:606)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkSer
vlet.java:657)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServl
et.java:525)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:46
6)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:612)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:139)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:510)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.doStart(Jetty6PluginWebAppContext.java
:110)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:
156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6PluginServer.start(Jetty6PluginServer.java:132)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:371)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:307)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.AbstractJettyRunMojo.execute(AbstractJettyRunMojo.java:203)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo.execute(Jetty6RunMojo.java:184)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.j
ava:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBu
ilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBu
ilder.java:76)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
        at 

[INFO] Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
[INFO] Starting scanner at interval of 10 seconds.
```

also its started but its give me

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

RequestURI=/GMS

Powered by jetty://
```

my pom.xml is

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.178</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.efsavage.twitter.bootstrap</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-maven</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

any hints please?

Comment: One of your XML files is not adhering to the schema. Check the XML files in an IDE for any error, like missing tags

Comment: Provide the file `/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml`. Also, don't mix Spring versions: you have spring-context 4.0.5 and spring-web (and others) of 4.0.0 version.

Comment: You are mixing Spring Versions (4.0.0 and 4.0.5) and Spring Security versions (3.2.4 and 3.0.3) and probably (due to the versions mixup) this will add some other Spring versions (or jars from versions) to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the Bill of Material poms provided by Spring and Spring Security together with  properties for the versions this will simplify your dependency management and version conflicts.

1. Add properties voor spring and spring security version
2. Include the bom for SPring Security and SPring
3. Cleanup dependencies

**Add Properties**

In your `pom.xml` add the following (I generally put them at the top for easy access).

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-security.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
</properties>
```

**Include the BOM**

Add a `dependencyManagement` section to import the 2 bom projects

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Notice the reference to the version properties provided earlier. Now if you want to update Spring you only have to change 1 thing and that is the property `spring.version`.

**Cleanup dependencies**

Due to the use of the bom and the fact that we import them you can cleanup your dependency section. Simply remove all the version elements and not directly needed dependencies (those will be pulled in transitively).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
// Non Spring Dependencies ommitted
</dependencies>
```

Those are the only Spring Dependencies you need.

A couple of final notes

1. It isn't recommended to use commons-logging but to use slf4j instead see [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging)
2. Use versionless xsd in your xml configuration files `spring-beans.xsd` instead of `spring-beans-4.0.xsd`. This will ensure that you always use the most compatible version of the xsd for your version spring.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i got this error now after i did your steps

Comment: [ERROR] Internal error: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {org.spri
ngframework.security:spring-security-web:null:jar}: The version cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRT
Exception: For artifact {org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:null:jar}: The version can
not be empty.

Comment: Make sure that you removed the `version` element and not made it empty and that you have the correct `properties` and names.

Comment: i have edited the question included the new pom.xml please have a look at it and yes i did remove the versions as you can see

Comment: Read my answer again, you must have **both** a `dependencyManagment` section, for the imports and a `dependencies` section for your dependencies. You have merged them and that isn't going to work. `dependencyManagent` != `dependencies`.

Comment: thanks so much for its working now, but i dont understand the that the old project got the old pom and the same servlet-xml and the web.xml and was working fine,any way i tried slf4j but jetty was always asking for a class not found in the commons-logging

Comment: You also need `jcl-over-slf4j` next to the `slf4j-api`. That is explained at the link I provided.